# Returning form variables in same JSP as form in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm working on a simple web app and part of the part is a search. Currently I'm just trying to return the form variables from the search, and display them on the search page once the user hits submit.

HTML:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="Search" action="performSearch" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <fieldset>
                                  <div class="form-bottom">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="profession" name="profession">
                                            <option value="General Contractor">General Contractor</option>
                                            <option value="Plumber">Plumber</option>                                        
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <form:input path="zipcode" type="text" name="form-zip" placeholder="Zipcode..." class="form-control"></form:input>
                                    </div>                                  
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                         <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>

                                        <form:input path="cost" type="text" name="form-cost" placeholder="Max Cost per Hour..." class="form-control"></form:input>
                                    </div>  
                                    <br>

                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default custom_btn" value="Search">

                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                    </form:form>
```

HTML to Display after searching.

```
    <c:if test="${not empty test1}">
                test1       
    </c:if>             
    <c:if test="${not empty test2}">
                test2       
    </c:if> 
    <c:if test="${not empty test2}">
                test3       
    </c:if>
```

Controller for search.jsp.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/performSearch")
    public ModelAndView performSearch(@ModelAttribute("search")Search search, ModelMap model) {


        model.addAttribute("test1",search.getCost());
        model.addAttribute("test2",search.getProfession());
        model.addAttribute("test2",search.getZipcode());


        return new ModelAndView("search");

    }
```

I think at this point I'm just having trouble figuring out what to return. Do I want to return a ModelAndView?

Edit:

So I forgot to return the model and model object. In this case,

return new ModelAndView("search", "Search", new Search());

Search being an object I created to hold the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the model and view object will take the name of the view passed in the constructor. In this case a JSP. The view resolver will wire this together for us. The model content will be made available in the JSP. In your case search.jsp. the model and view object is just a handy way of combining the model data with the view. You can also create them them different ways. Your on the right path.

Comment: Ok so it looks like I forgot to return the model and model object. I was only returning the view.

Answer (score 0):

I create the model and view this way

ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("someview");

mav.addObject("someobject", myObject);

return mav;

You can then access someobject implicitly from someview.jsp using EL